# Sorting by Children in Entity Framework doesn't return sorted list

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know that Entity framework doesn't support sort or filter in the children collections yet. What I thought is that first I get the data then use `foreach` loop to sort it. The result gives me an unsorted list. My goal is to get the `Participants` (any order) and `CurrentHospitaliztions` (order by id descending) which is a child of participants. The models and the query is below. Any help will be appriciated.

```
public class Participant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .. other fields

    public ICollection<CurrentHospitalization> CurrentHospitalizations { get; set; }

    public Participant()
    {
        CurrentHospitalizations = new Collection<CurrentHospitalization>();
    }
}

public class CurrentHospitalization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .. other fields

    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

}
```

The query that I use:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Participant>> GetList()
{
     var participants = await context.Participants
        .Include(x => x.CurrentHospitalizations)
        .ToListAsync();

        foreach (var p in participants )
        {
            var s = p.CurrentHospitalizations;
            foreach (var q in s)
            {
                s.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id);
            }
        }

        return participants ;
}
```

Comment: Can you not sort in main query? `.Include(x => x.CurrentHospitalizations).OrderByDescending(x => x.CurrentHospitalizations.Id).ToListAsync()`

Comment: `OrderByDescending` does not actually perform any in-place sorting. It returns a sorted enumerable/queryable instead. So if you don’t make use of its return value, then you are doing effectively nothing.

Comment: This is a common mis-understanding of how ```IEnumerable``` in general works (to include ```IQueryable```.  As stated above, ```a.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id);``` will never be called because it's never used.  It doesn't assign directly; it's just a reference to that query.  However; even though you cannot sort by children with EF you can still sort by the children via join.  There's no need to pull in the entire database and then sort; you can't dot operator to the children but you can still reach that data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sorted the right piece, in the wrong place, and then didn't really do anything with it. You don't need the nested iteration, you can just do it from the single foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (var p in participants) 
    p.CurrentHospitalizations = p.CurrentHospitalizations.OrderByDescending( ch => ch.Id ).ToList();
```

Comment: If you are curious about the general workings of IEnumerable, or LINQ in general, please see Jon Skeet's explanation of the *entire* topic here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/ . Make sure to scroll to the table of contents. It is an absolute must read.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for the help! I really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you ahve here is a failure to understand the basics of LINQ and not reading the manual.

```
        var s = p.CurrentHospitalizations;
        foreach (var q in s)
        {
            s.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id);
        }
```

does effectively nothing else than waste processor time.

You make a variable s. You assign to it the current hospuzatlizations, not sorted.

Then you call OrderByDescending - generating an expression that you COULD execute, except you never DO execute it. So, you created some object tree and - throw it away.

o.CurrentHospitalizations = s.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).ToList()

would assign s to be a list and execute it. The ToList() is missing - as well as the assigning it, so the sorted result is not just thrown away.

Those are LINQ basics - orderby etc. are not changing order, they return an ordered result, and you must materialize it.

Comment: That's not understanding the basics of LINQ; that's understanding the basics of ```IEnumerable```; the base of all of it.  All ```IEnumerable``` types work this way regardless of LINQ.

Comment: You guys just could direct me the link or source (so that I could read and learn more) instead of judging my understanding of this concept.